# Visual Studio Ctrl + '-' equivalent in Intellij

Tags: visual-studio, intellij-idea, visual-studio-2017, keyboard-shortcuts

In VS 2017 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> is for navigate backward.

What is the equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> in IntelliJ?

Comment: what do you mean for "navigate backward?" already checked this jetbrains thread ? https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206573029-Way-to-jump-back-to-previous-file-line-after-Ctrl-clicking-function-call-

Comment: Thanks @SimoneCelia, ctrl + alt + left do the work.